# Dismissing Popup by mouse or touch can cause a click event

Tags: wpf, popup, touch

I have view with a number of buttons running commands in the viewmodel.

When I display a settings Popup over the top, and then dismiss it by touching outside, the touch event also causes a click event on the button that was under my touch point. I do not want that button click to happen. Some of the buttons are still visible when the popup is open.

I use `StaysOpen=True` and manage the popup dismissal myself as for some reason the Popup does not close itself when I touch outside (mouse is Ok). The code to dismiss the popup is as follows:-

```cs
private void Grid_PreviewTouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    var tp = e.GetTouchPoint(optionsPopupChild).Position;
    if (optionsPopup.IsOpen && !((tp.X >= 0 && tp.X < optionsPopupChild.ActualWidth) && (tp.Y >= 0 && tp.Y < optionsPopupChild.ActualHeight)))
    {
        optionsPopup.IsOpen = false;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

I have also tried setting `e.Handled = true` in the `PreviewTouchUp` handler similarly but a click event still gets thru to the button causing the Command to run. I was under the impression that settings `e.Handled = true` should prevent mouse promotion of the touch.

Help appreciated.

Jerry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a rectangle or something on top of everything in your main window.

Give it a low opacity or transparent fill.

( You might have to set it focusable.)

Set that visible whilst showing your popup. Set it collapsed when not. That way when they try and click or touch something they shouldn't be able to, they can't.

Have you considered what happens if they want to run some other app?

Instead of handling clicks and touches elsewhere and just in your app consider handling isfocuswithinchanged on a parent control inside your popup. That way when they click on anything outside that popup it loses focus and you can dismiss the popup.

You could also consider making your popup just a panel inside your parent window and have a "submit" or "OK" button in it drives whatever should happen when they're finished with it.

Comment: Thanks, I had already tried the canvas or panel approach you describe and it didn't help but I have revisited it and by adding an async delay before collapsing the canvas and that seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So the suggestion from Andy works for me, which is to open and close a canvas behind the popup to swallow the rogue click event, but the delay is also required!

```
private async void Grid_PreviewTouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    var tp = e.GetTouchPoint(optionsPopupChild).Position;
    if (optionsPopup.IsOpen && !((tp.X >= 0 && tp.X < optionsPopupChild.ActualWidth) && (tp.Y >= 0 && tp.Y < optionsPopupChild.ActualHeight)))
    {
        optionsPopup.IsOpen = false;
        e.Handled = true;
        await TaskDelay(100);
        transCanvas.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
    }
}
```